# Sinking Events in GWT--Compatibility with other JS frameworks

Tags: events, gwt, onclick, compatibility, addeventlistener

I notice that in GWT's DOMStandardImpl.java, events are sunk by setting the onevent properties on the element to refer to an event dispatcher. e.g.,

```
protected native void sinkEventsImpl(Element elem, int bits) /*-{
...
if (chMask & 0x00001) elem.onclick       = (bits & 0x00001) ?
        @com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.DOMImplStandard::dispatchEvent : null;
...
}-*/;
```

The problem with that is that this may be a source of incompatibility with existing JavaScript code and other JS frameworks. Why do they use the elem.onevent=func method as opposed to the preferred

```
elem.addEventListener('event',func,false);
```

which would allow the developer to add multiple event listeners to the element?

Thanks.
Troy

Answer (score 2):

GWT's `DOMImpl` have been (at least by the time they were written) benchmarked to use the fastest option depending on the browser; this is why `DOMImplStandard` uses event handler properties (and why [`DOMImplOpera`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/impl/DOMImplOpera.java) doesn't have the `if chMask & 0x00001)` part, because assigning the `onxxx` property is so fast there).

As for the potential incompatibility with other frameworks:

1. GWT is built around the idea that it *owns* the elements it creates, so if you have a third-party JS lib that messes up with it, it's your fault (for trying to use both of them at the same time)
2. it could still be an issue with elements that you `wrap()` inside a widget (that also includes `RootPanel.get(String)`), but then again, you're held responsible if things don't play well together.
3. more importantly, using event handler properties in GWT won't be an issue if the other JS libs don't use them, and isntead use `addEventListener` (or IE's `attachEvent`). So if you do have an incompatibility/conflict, first blame yourself (see above), then blame *both* GWT and your JS lib.

In brief: it's a non-issue.

Comment: I was hoping to use some of the UI components of a third-party JS lib  in some of my custom, more complex GWT widgets so I don't have to write them myself. Supposing that there were no compatibility issues, do you still think this would be not advisable? Thanks.

Comment: _Supposing that there were no compatibility issues,_ then go ahead! Google Groups makes use of the Closure Library's rich editor, and Google Flights makes use of Google Maps API. You'd probably better not mixing event handlers (for the same event, handled both in GWT and in the third-party JS) but as I said, there's little to no reason it'd fail (unless the third-party JS also uses `onxxx`, and then you could possibly simply use two elements wrapped in one another rather than listening from both GWT and JS on the same element)